# Java - Assign elements of ArrayList to array using forEach and lambda

Tags: arrays, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have an ArrayList and want to assign its elements to an array. I can do it using classic old java code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Mango");
list.add("Apple");
list.add("Banana");
list.add("Grapes");

String[] optionCode = new String[4];

// Before Java 7
System.out.println("Before Java 7:");
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    optionCode[i] = list.get(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < optionCode.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Element " + i + " is: " + optionCode[i]);
}
```

Now I want to use new java 8 features: forEach and lambda method:

```
list.stream().forEach(i -> {
    optionCode[i] = i;
    System.out.println(i);
});
```

It complains: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe just `String[] optionCode = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`?

Comment: @ernest_k [Don’t specify a non-zero initial size for `toArray`](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/), `String[] optionCode = list.toArray(new String[0]);` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the stream `toArray()` method here:

```java
String[] optionCode = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(optionCode));
```

This prints:

```
[Mango, Apple, Banana, Grapes]
```

Comment: a side note: if JDK >=11, no need to ```stream()``` we can use just ```list.toArray(String[]::new)```.  I read some benchmark about ```toArray()``` from Shipilev's  https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/ url, ```Object []```  perform faster. Just a thought.

Comment: @prostýčlověk the authors of the new `toArray` method considered the finding of that article, so `toArray(String[]::new)` does the same as the old `toArray(new String[0])`…

Answer (score 1):

Tim Biegeleisen already suggested the solution to your problem.

The reason, however, that it doesn't work, is that you are trying to access both the index and the element at that index. With `forEach`, you don't have access to the index.

---

If you *really* need to use the index sometime (because, for example, you want to filter out the element at index *n*), you could use `IntStream`:

```java
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(i -> i != n)
    .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i))   // Or mapToObj(List::get)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution without using forEach.

`String[] optionCode = list.toArray(n -> new String[n]);`

Comment: You have missed stream(). String[] optionCode = list..stream().toArray(n -> new String[n]);

Comment: Without adding stram(), I got compile error: The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> n) -> {})

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. It was perfectly working on my compiler. Now, I find that without .stream(), it won't work in all the compilers. Thank you.

Comment: This is not compiler dependent. Just identify [the method you’re invoking](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) and note the “Since 11” in its documentation. So it works in Java 11 and newer. By the way, `n -> new String[n]` is the same as `String[]::new`. In older Java versions, you can simply use `String[] optionCode = list.toArray(new String[0]);` instead.